# Verification of Zend Installation framework (2.4.8) on WAMP server in Windows 8.1

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to PHP programming. Recently I have installed Zend framework 2.4.7 on WAMP server (version 2.5) on windows 8 environment.

To verify the installation I ran the installation checker script but it is throwing the exception "openssl extension missing" 
I followed other links to resolve this issue e.g. uncommenting extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file but no luck.

[openssl error]
Kindly assist on resolving this issue.

Regards,

Rahul W

Comment: There are 2 php.ini in Wampserver so you have to make changes in another one reside in `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.ini`.